# Deleting files in a folder Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, delete-file

I have created a python 3.4 script to delete files in a foler(Temp files o fWindows Folder)

**Here it is but it is not working**

```
import os, subprocess
del_dir = r'C:\Users\vaibhav2\AppData\Local\Temp'
pObj = subprocess.Popen('del /S /Q /F %s\\*.*' % del_dir, shell=True, 
stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
rTup = pObj.communicate()
rCod = pObj.returncode
if rCod == 0:
    print ('Success: Cleaned Windows Temp Folder')
else:
    print('Fail: Unable to Clean Windows Temp Folder')
```

**EDIT**

**Some of the code has been edited**
The error I am facing is that it deletes only some files instead of ALL files in %tmp% folder of Windows  ,even if I run the script as Admin.
If it requires authentication please provide the code for providing password to this command of admin because I can't do right click run as admin every time

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have permissions to do so. I do not think you have permissions. What error do you get?

Comment: No error at all

Comment: this is what I get   Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: How to get Permissions ? I am logged in Windows as Admin + there is no password on the admin user

Comment: Can you delete files manually? If you can not delete them manually, you can not delete them with Python either.

Comment: Run script as Admin. Give it a try.

Comment: I tried using Admin I ran cmd using admin then typed python filename.py still no effect

Comment: Can u add the code to run the script using Admin

Comment: Can you run script `run as Admin` without cmd?

Comment: Question updated sorry about inconvenience

Comment: Try listing the directory with `os.listdir`, deleting files with `os.remove`, and recursively deleting subdirectories with `shutil.rmtree`. You'll have more control and direct feedback regarding any Windows errors that get raised.

Comment: I see you originally had something close to the above suggestion, before changing it to use the shell. However, your original code incorrectly used the base name `f` instead of the fully-qualified name `p = os.path.join(del_dir, f)`.

Comment: please edit that question body, its irritating.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the comments and answers posted. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "f" is just a filename, without the path. So your tests will fail unless your current directory is the del_dir. You need to do a os.path.join(del_dir, f) to get the full path to pass to your tests.

Comment: Secondly ur ans is incorect plz remove it